# How to specify color per side of a cube in OpenGL ES application?

Tags: opengl-es

I have a cube define in the code below. I want to specify color for each of the 6 faces like:

front face: color1

back face: color2

left face: color3

right face: color4

top face: color5

bottom face: color6

Note that in OpenGL ES we only have triangles and not quads. I am looking for working sample code that solves my problem because working sample code is worth more than a thousand words like they say about pictures.

Here is the cube:

```
 float vertices[] = { -width, -height, -depth, // 0
                              width, -height, -depth, // 1
                              width,  height, -depth, // 2

                             -width,  height, -depth, // 3

                             -width, -height,  depth, // 4


                              width, -height,  depth, // 5

                              width,  height,  depth, // 6

                             -width,  height,  depth // 7
        };  
  short indices[] = { 0, 2, 1,
                0, 3, 2,

                1,2,6,
                6,5,1,

                4,5,6,
                6,7,4,

                2,3,6,
                6,3,7,

                0,7,3,
                0,4,7,

                0,1,5,
                0,5,4
                         };
```

This is the drawing code:

```
 gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);
        // Enable face culling.
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
        // What faces to remove with the face culling.
        gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_BACK);
        // Enabled the vertices buffer for writing and to be used during
        // rendering.
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

        // Specifies the location and data format of an array of vertex
        // coordinates to use when rendering.
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mVerticesBuffer);


            // Bind the texture according to the set texture filter
            gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[filter]);
            gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);


       if (mColorBuffer != null) {
            // Enable the color array buffer to be used during rendering.
            gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
            gl.glColorPointer(4, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mColorBuffer);
        }



        gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, mNumOfIndices,
                GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, mIndicesBuffer);

        // ALL the DRAWING IS DONE NOW

        // Disable the vertices buffer.
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);


            gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);


        // Disable face culling.
        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is desktop GLUT code but the core logic should translate directly to OpenGL ES:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <cstdlib>

void glutTexturedCube(GLdouble size)
{
    GLfloat color1[] = { 255,   0,   0 };
    GLfloat color2[] = {   0, 255,   0 };
    GLfloat color3[] = {   0,   0, 255 };
    GLfloat color4[] = { 255, 255,   0 };
    GLfloat color5[] = {   0, 255, 255 };
    GLfloat color6[] = { 255, 255, 255 };

    GLfloat color[] = {
        color1[0], color1[1], color1[2],
        color1[0], color1[1], color1[2],
        color1[0], color1[1], color1[2],
        color1[0], color1[1], color1[2],
        color1[0], color1[1], color1[2],
        color1[0], color1[1], color1[2],

        color2[0], color2[1], color2[2],
        color2[0], color2[1], color2[2],
        color2[0], color2[1], color2[2],
        color2[0], color2[1], color2[2],
        color2[0], color2[1], color2[2],
        color2[0], color2[1], color2[2],

        color3[0], color3[1], color3[2],
        color3[0], color3[1], color3[2],
        color3[0], color3[1], color3[2],
        color3[0], color3[1], color3[2],
        color3[0], color3[1], color3[2],
        color3[0], color3[1], color3[2],

        color4[0], color4[1], color4[2],
        color4[0], color4[1], color4[2],
        color4[0], color4[1], color4[2],
        color4[0], color4[1], color4[2],
        color4[0], color4[1], color4[2],
        color4[0], color4[1], color4[2],

        color5[0], color5[1], color5[2],
        color5[0], color5[1], color5[2],
        color5[0], color5[1], color5[2],
        color5[0], color5[1], color5[2],
        color5[0], color5[1], color5[2],
        color5[0], color5[1], color5[2],

        color6[0], color6[1], color6[2],
        color6[0], color6[1], color6[2],
        color6[0], color6[1], color6[2],
        color6[0], color6[1], color6[2],
        color6[0], color6[1], color6[2],
        color6[0], color6[1], color6[2],
    };

    GLfloat vert[] = {
        // top (+z)
        -1, -1,  1,
         1, -1,  1,
        -1,  1,  1,
        -1,  1,  1,
         1, -1,  1,
         1,  1,  1, 

        // bottom (-z)
        -1, -1, -1,
        -1,  1, -1,
         1, -1, -1,
         1, -1, -1,
        -1,  1, -1,
         1,  1, -1,

        // right (+x)
         1, -1, -1, 
         1,  1, -1, 
         1, -1,  1, 
         1, -1,  1, 
         1,  1, -1, 
         1,  1,  1, 

        // left (-x)
        -1, -1, -1, 
        -1, -1,  1, 
        -1,  1, -1, 
        -1,  1, -1, 
        -1, -1,  1, 
        -1,  1,  1, 

        // front (+y)
        -1, -1, -1,
         1, -1, -1,
        -1, -1,  1,
        -1, -1,  1,
         1, -1, -1,
         1, -1,  1,

        // back (-y)
        -1,  1, -1,
        -1,  1,  1,
         1,  1, -1,
         1,  1, -1,
        -1,  1,  1,
         1,  1,  1,
    };

    GLushort idxs[] = { 
         0, 1, 2, 
         3, 4, 5,

         6, 7, 8,
         9,10,11,

        12,13,14,
        15,16,17,

        18,19,20,
        21,22,23,

        24,25,26,
        27,28,29,

        30,31,32,
        33,34,35
    };

    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, color);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vert);

    glPushMatrix();
    glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
    glScaled(size, size, size);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, sizeof(idxs)/sizeof(idxs[0]), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, idxs);
    glPopMatrix();

    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
} 

static GLuint texName;

void init(void)
{
    glClearColor(0,0,0,0);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
}

void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // projection
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); glLoadIdentity();
    int viewport[4]; glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);
    gluPerspective(60.0, (GLdouble)viewport[2]/(GLdouble)viewport[3], 1.0, 100.0 );

    // view transform
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0,0,-4);

    // render 
    glPushMatrix();
    const float ANGLE_SPEED = 30; // degrees/sec
    float angle = ANGLE_SPEED * (glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME) / 1000.0f);
    glRotatef(angle*0.5f, 1, 0, 0);
    glRotatef(angle, 0, 1, 0);
    glRotatef(angle*0.7f, 0, 0, 1);

    glutTexturedCube(1);

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h);
}

void keyboard (unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    switch (key) 
        { 
        case 27: exit(0); break;
        default: break; 
        }
}

void idle()
{
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow (argv[0]);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutIdleFunc(idle);

    init();
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but this does not work for me as the definition of the cube I have is very different from the cube defined in this code.

Comment: @Alan: Might want to refine your question then.

Comment: @Alan - Actually, his `color` array will do just what you want.  Ignore the rest of the cube design, and use that.  Like your cube, his specifies two triangles for each face using six indices, so it will draw each face of a cube in a different color.  You may need to change the ordering of the overall colors to align them with the numbering you want for your faces, but that's trivial to do once you've integrated this with your application and have the cube drawing.